# Recursive palindrome checker

Tags: java, recursion, substring

This is my code to check if a word is a palindrome but I have no clue on how to start this.

I really need help with this method

```
public static boolean pallindrome (String word1) {

int count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i< s1.length(); i++){
           if(s1.length/2 = 1)
           return false;
       }
       if(count == s1.length()-1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

I have no clue on how to start this method

Comment: Do you have a definition of *palindrome*?

Answer (score 4):

Well, think of it this way...

- If you have a word, can you tell *some* information about whether it's a palindrome just by looking at its ends?
- Once you've looked at its ends, how might you reduce the problem?
- How can you tell when you're done?

(Trying just to steer your thoughts a little rather than giving you the whole solution...)

Answer (score 1):

I think that every large palindrome has a smaller palindrome in it.  If you use that reasoning, then you should be able to make a recursive algorithm

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a word that is the same forwards and backwards.  All recursive problems need a base case.  In your example the base case is a word of length 1.  A word of length 1 will always be a palindrome.

```
function palindrome(String s)  
{   
    if(s.length() == 1)  
    {  
        return true;
    }    
  //Your code goes here
}
```

Now you need to hand `palindrome` progressively smaller strings that will result in the function being able to complete.  You will want to use the indices of the String to make it smaller.